# A good IPFIX analyzer

Tags: networking, firewall

I was looking for recommendations for IPFIX analyzers to use with sonicwall firewalls. I experienced sticker shock when I saw prices ranged between $3500 to $7000 per license. Are there any free, open source, or more reasonably priced windows-based options available?

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To report on traditional NetFlow, any reporting tool will work with the SonicWALL.

For the IPFIX with extensions, the SonicWALL Scrutinizer cross references many of the flow templates to build the specialized IPFIX reports (e.g. top URLs). For most people, the open source projects won't come close to the quality of the reporting.  You get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

The [pmacct project](http://www.pmacct.net/) will collect IPFIX, Netflow, and other traffic flow protocols. I haven't used it, personally, but looking at the feature list and documentation it looks fairly nice (easy to get data into third-party applications or databases, has a nice "constellation" of related projects orbiting it, etc). If you're not afraid of working with free/open-source software I think it would be a good first place to look.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I forgot to include that I was looking for windows-based tools. pmacct seems to only run on *nix, unfortunately.

Comment: @ForceFlow: It looks like there are quite a number of Windows references in the pmacct wiki, and I see IFDEF's in some of the code for building on Win32. I don't know that you're totally out of luck (though you'd probably have a better time of it just using Linux or a Free Unix operating system, in terms of ease of installation and applicability of third-party scripts and guides.)